# Presence of session variable or cookie causes authorization (OAuth) failure with Google Plus API in PHP

Tags: php, google-plus, google-openid

When the user gets to my page (similar to the Google Plus API PHP starter), my app needs the authorization to access the user's profile. The callback URI I set is the page itself. Initially, everything worked perfectly: the user comes back to my page with successful authorization ($authUrl is not set, while $me and $activities are set).

However, now I need to pass a parameter called 'id' from before the authorization to after and this seems to MESS EVERYTHING UP :-(

If there is a session variable or a cookie when the authorization request is sent, the user comes back to my page without the authorization ($authUrl is set, while $me and $activities are NULL).

Even more weird: after using

**setcookie('storedid', $_GET['id'], time()+3600, '/', '.mydomain.com');**

the user comes back WITHOUT authorization), while with:

**setcookie('storedid', $_GET['id'], $expire, '/anysubfolder/', '.mydomain.com');**

it works perfectly! Also, at some point I made a typo and $_GET['id'] was NULL and, even if the cookie was in the '/' path, the authorization was successful!

Is there a way I can pass a parameter from before to after the authorization?

I'm starting to think about crazy stuff (writing the 'id' to a SQL table, together with the user's IP address and retrieving it with a query after the authorization) but it is not robust and frankly it would suck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a `state` parameter with the user when they got to authorize access as [described in the OAuth 2 spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-22#section-4.1.1) and it will be returned with the user.

For example `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?state=xyz123&scrope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me...`

Comment: Hi Abraham,thanks a lot for your answer! Very much appreciated and sorry I replied so late. It works perfectly!